# How to set focus to Firefox window using Web Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to create a Firefox addon that will bring the browser window to the forefront whenever a given event is fired.

This is my manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Test browser extension",

  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },

  "permissions": [
    "notifications",
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

Content.js:

```
'use strict';

document.addEventListener('newOrderEvent', function() {
  console.log('New Order event received');
  browser.runtime.sendMessage('new-order-event');
});
```

Background.js:

```
'use strict';

var windowId;

function newOrderListener(message) {
  if (message === 'new-order-event') {
    console.log('Received event!');
    browser.windows.update(windowId, {
      drawAttention: true,
      focused: true,
      state: 'maximized'
    });
  }
}

browser.windows.getCurrent().then(function(window) {
  windowId = window.id;
});

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(newOrderListener);
```

The `newOrderEvent` is generated by my application's webpage and it is always being called at the right time, however sometimes the browser comes to the foreground and other times it doesn't and I don't understand exactly why. Furthermore the console output from the background.js is not being registered by the browser.

What I am doing wrong?

Note: I am using Firefox 52 and Windows 10.

Comment: 1: do you get any warnings when you "install" the extension? 2: Browser console (Ctrl+Shift+J) definitely shows all the console.log's 3: your use of `windowId` in `background.js` looks wrong, can't put a finger on it just yet

Comment: Hi,  no I don't get any warnings... I also used the  `Ctrl+Shift+J` console and the `console.log()` commands are now appearing...

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a TAB to make itself focused, then you are mistaken with what windowId is. WindowId will be the ID of the window, not of a tab, and the way you are setting it, it will only ever be a single value, the first windowID when the extension is loaded

if you change background.js to the following

```
function newOrderListener(message, sender) {
    if (message === 'new-order-event') {
        console.log('Received event for window %s, tab %s', sender.tab.windowId, sender.tab.id);
        browser.windows.update(sender.tab.windowId, {
            drawAttention: true, 
            focused: true, 
            state: 'maximized'}
        ).then(() => browser.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {
            active: true
        }));
    }
}
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(newOrderListener);
```

Then any tab that has the content script loaded (which is basically every tab in your code) will be able to focus itself by

```
document.dispatchEvent(new Event("newOrderEvent"))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, your code does looks better and I like not having to use a promise to get the `windowId`, however it is still not working. Sometimes it puts the browser on the foreground and other times the browser just blinks on the status bar.

Comment: Hum... are you using Windows? 
Note: I have also been experimenting with addional addons and this code works for me if I set the browser to be "always on top"...